# Agora SDK video not working, even local video not showing up in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, agora.io

I have setup the agora SDK for one of my iOS project and got a developer app ID from agora, follow the each step that had on tutorials but nothing seems to work... just run the app and showing only the UIView (canvas) for both local and remote video, not error - no warning found relative to this.. I download and edit the sample app from the agora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guys I found the answer with little shy, it was a error with APPID, I have copied APPID from the developer account one less character.

Conclusion: Wrong appID will not give any error just run the APP, but when I put the correct APPID that I have created it appears the local video, then I tried with another phone with same channelID then the remote video also appears fine... so even to activate the local video only, have to put a correct APPID CREATED ON AGORA DEVELOPER ACCOUNT.

EDIT: App id is used at two places in Agora, First is in Agora signal API and second is i RTCEngine so make sure same APP id is placed on both locations

Best Regards.

Comment: What is Agora Signal API? Is it for generating the token? I used heruko to generate a token. Is that the same thing?

Comment: @AnzyShQ it depends on what're you trying to do with the Signal API. Usually Agora SDK is handling all that signalling (no need to worry about handling Turn/ICE candidates) stuff for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorted it out. Can we also know if a user has joined the channel from either mobile or web end ?